# Best way to implement --verbose flag globally in a python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

I have a python project with multiple functions. I've implemented verbose printing in one of the functions the following way

```
def func(a, b=None, verbose=False):
    verboseprint = print if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None
    
    verboseprint('only if verbose')
    print('always printed')

>> func(2)
always printed
>> func(2, verbose=True)
only if verbose
always printed
```

It's working as a debugging tool for me. Now, I want to implement this in multiple other functions, and I don't know if defining this in each function is the best way. I tried defining it as a function in my config.py and import it, but it's not working as expected.

```
config.py
----------
verbose = False
def verboseprint(text):
    print(text) if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None

main.py
-------
from config import verboseprint

def func(a, b=None, verbose=False):
    verboseprint('only if verbose')
    print('always printed')

>> from main import func
>> func(a)
always printed
>> func(a, verbose=True)
always printed
```

As you can see, the verbose flag doesn't seem to be working, because the verboseprint definition seems to be going by the verbose value in its local module (config.py). I tried using nonlocal, but it's failing at config.py because there's no nonlocal verbose  there.

How do I implement this function and import it elsewhere?

I'm able to implement it this way, but I would much rather not pass the verbose flag every time I call the function.

```
config.py
----------
def verboseprint(text, verbose=False):
    print(text) if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None

main.py
-------
from config import verboseprint

def func(a, b=None, verbose=False):
    verboseprint('only if verbose', verbose)
    print('always printed')

>> from main import func
>> func(a)
always printed
>> func(a, verbose=True)
only if verbose
always printed
```

Comment: Maybe consider having a global function that handles verbose printing?

Comment: as an aside, `print(text) if verbose else lambda *a, **k: None` is confusing, why are you making the `else` condition evlauate to a function? You don't do anything with it. The whole thing should jsut be an if statement: `if verbose: print(text)`

Comment: "because the verboseprint definition seems to be going by the verbose value in its local module (config.py)." that is *always* how Python works. Just use `import config` and `config.verbose = False` or whatever, and `config.verboseprint(text)`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a logging library, you could just set the verbosity there and the logging library would handle the rest for you. Then you just need to determine if each message is a debug message, info, etc.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("application name") #use a global variable or parent/child loggers to inherit formatting and levels, etc.
logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO) # logging.DEBUG etc.
```

Then to use:

```
logger.info("info message")
logger.debug("debug message") # only shows if verbosity level set
```